# ant junit selenium wont run in jenkins

Tags: selenium, ant, junit, jenkins

I have junit tests that use selenium to test web server.
When i run the tests using ant from command line, everything is working fine, browser gets opened and tests are going as planed.Browser gets open and i can see tests running.
Recently ive tried to add automatic tests as part of Ci cycle running on jenkins.
I run it as ant build command.
I can see that ant is executing properly (test classes are built i can see output from tests to console) but browser window never gets opened and test fails because of it. here is my ant file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<project name="JUNIT" default="main" basedir="../../project"         xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"> 
<!-- Sets variables which can later be used. --> 
<!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} --> 
    <property name="api.dir" location="src/java" />     
    <property name="build.api.dir" location="target/classes" />
    <property name="test.dir" location="src/test/java" />   
    <property name="build.test.dir" location="target" /> 
    <!-- Variables used for JUnit testin --> 
    <property name="test.report.dir" location="testreport" /> 
    <!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling--> 

    <path id="api.class.path"> 
        <pathelement location="${build.api.dir}" />         
    </path>

     <artifact:dependencies cacheDependencyRefs="true" pathId="pomdeps.path">
      <pom file="pom.xml"/>
    </artifact:dependencies>

    <target name="clean">       
        <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" /> 
        <delete dir="${build.api.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${build.test.dir}" />
    </target> <!-- Creates the build, docs and dist directory--> 

    <target name="makedir"> 
        <echo message="Make dir"/>      
        <mkdir dir="${build.test.dir}" /> 
        <mkdir dir="${build.api.dir}" /> 

        <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" /> 
    </target> <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit --> 

    <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir"> 
        <echo message="Compile"/>   
        <javac srcdir="${api.dir}" destdir="${build.api.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <!--classpath refid="junit.class.path" />           
            <classpath refid="libs.class.path" /-->
            <classpath refid="pomdeps.path" />
        </javac>        
        <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${build.test.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <!--classpath refid="junit.class.path" /--> 
            <classpath refid="api.class.path" /> 
            <classpath refid="pomdeps.path" />

        </javac> 
    </target> 
    <!-- Run the JUnit Tests --> <!-- Output is XML, could also be plain--> 
    <echo message="Classes folder ${build.test.dir}"/>
    <target name="junit" depends="compile" > 
        <echo message="junit"/>
        <junit printsummary="on" fork="false" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="true"> 
        <classpath refid="pomdeps.path" /> 
            <classpath>                 
                <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}"/>     
                <pathelement location="${build.api.dir}"/>              
            </classpath> 

            <formatter usefile="false" type="plain"/>
            <batchtest fork="no" todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            </fileset>
            </batchtest>

        </junit> 
    </target> 

    <target name="main" depends="compile, junit"> 
        <description>Main target</description> 
    </target> 
</project>
```

Jenkins is 1.591 i installed it with default parameters as windows installation downloaded from their site.
Can it be something wrong with jenkins? Do i miss something?

Comment: If i start Jenkins from command line, java -jar jenkins.war - everything works ok!!!

Comment: Turns our the problem was with Windows Services Permissions.When running as Windows Service jenkins has limited permissions in terms of Desktop apps interaction. But if we run it from command line under some real user permissions it works ok. Need to figure out how to run Jenkins as console program on startup of the windows and we will have working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned earlier the problem was lack of UI permissions for Jenkins server.
1.configure Jenkins to run as service and make it login with real user name
2.Make sure that windows host that runs Jenkins logs on automaticaly after restart.